Using trigonometry to compute the position of an object inside of a drone picture
Assume I have a certain picture taken aerially by a drone. The yaw, pitch, and roll of the drone gimbal are known, and so are the horizontal and vertical FoV of the camera. We also know the $$x, y, z$$ coordinates the drone had while taking the picture.
In order to determine whether a point, given its $$x, y, z$$ coordinates (for example in UTM), is inside of the field of view of the image, I have been using the following algorithm:

Compute rotation matrices for yaw, pitch, and roll:

$$R_{\text{yaw}} = \begin{bmatrix}
   \cos(\text{yaw}) & -\sin(\text{yaw}) & 0 \\
   \sin(\text{yaw}) & \cos(\text{yaw}) & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1
   \end{bmatrix}
   $$
$$R_{\text{pitch}} = \begin{bmatrix}
   \cos(\text{pitch}) & 0 & \sin(\text{pitch}) \\
   0 & 1 & 0 \\
   -\sin(\text{pitch}) & 0 & \cos(\text{pitch})
   \end{bmatrix}
   $$
$$R_{\text{roll}} = \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & \cos(\text{roll}) & -\sin(\text{roll}) \\
   0 & \sin(\text{roll}) & \cos(\text{roll})
   \end{bmatrix}
$$

Construct the combined rotation matrix (R) as the product of these three matrices:
$$R = R_{\text{yaw}} \cdot R_{\text{pitch}} \cdot R_{\text{roll}}$$

Compute the view vector as: \begin{bmatrix}
\text{object}_x - \text{drone}_x \\
\text{object}_y - \text{drone}_y \\
\text{object}_z - \text{drone}_z
\end{bmatrix}

Multiply $R^T$ by the view vector: $$R^T \cdot view\_vector$$

Calculate the vertical and horizontal angle of the object with respect to the drone point of view:


Let $$t_1, t_2, t_3$$ be the first, second, and third element of $R\cdot view_vector$.
$$\theta_{\text{horizontal}} = \text{atan2}(t_2, t_1)
$$
$$\theta_{\text{vertical}} = \text{atan2}\left(t_3, \sqrt{t_1^2 + t_2^2}\right)
$$

The point is in the image if $$-{fov\_horizontal \over 2} \leq \theta_{horizontal} \leq {fov\_horizontal \over 2} \land -{fov\_vertical \over 2} \leq \theta_{vertical} \leq {fov\_vertical \over 2}$$. If so, we compute the relative pixels at which the object is located as:

$$
x\_rel = \frac{\theta_{horizontal} + {fov\_horizontal \over 2}}{fov\_horizontal}
$$
$$y\_rel = \frac{\theta_{vertical} + {fov\_vertical \over 2}}{fov\_vertical}
$$
We multiply $$x\_rel, y\_rel$$ times the image's width and height respectively to finally get the $$x, y$$ position of the point(s) in the image.
After trying out this procedure with some real images and point coordinates, I find that it often gives quite inaccurate results.
For example, in the picture below points 1, 2, 3, and 5 are pretty close to their detected positions (red marker), and there's a false positive for point 4. However, it doesn't look like I would be able to get points 1, 2, 3, and 5 to get to their correct position by simply rotating the picture (i.e. changing the yaw): there does seem to be some distortion going on.

I shared a Python implementation of the algorithm outlined here, with a test image + GCP coordinates to try it. This could help better visualize the calculations being done. Feel free to try it with different data.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RyRqqgmpOCH7elqE4_spCjAD2h61NRmY?usp=sharing
Am I making any mistakes in the various steps? Is there a better way to accomplish this task altogether?

This question is off-topic for Photo-SE. But as a photogrammetric question, it's right on topic at [gis.se].
